# Fit a small DataFrame with a simple function

Tags: python, dataframe, curve-fitting

I have a set of a lot of Dataframes with the following shape:

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'Y':[0.0455,0.079,0.059,0.144],'X':[0.055,0.110,0.165,0.220]})

`dat
Out[14]: 
        Y      X
    0  0.0455  0.055
    1  0.0790  0.110
    2  0.0590  0.165
    3  0.1440  0.220
```

I'm trying to fit this data with a function: Y = kX**m
My expected output is to get parameters 'k' and 'm'

Seems that is not a hard job to do, but I only find some examples using 'scipy.optimize.curve_fit' that requieres several rounds of simulation to fit the data and I think is too complicated only for a few numbers.
Some ideas?

CLUE: Using a commercial software I already know that
k = -0.3176
m = 0.8935

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not too *complicated* to follow the examples on `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).
Also, you won't get the same values as from the *commercial software* since your dataset is too small to be correctly fitted.

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, k, m):
    return k * (x**m)

dat = pd.DataFrame({'Y': [0.0455, 0.079, 0.059, 0.144], 'X': [0.055, 0.110, 0.165, 0.220]})

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, dat.X.values, dat.Y.values)
print('k:', popt[0])
print('m:', popt[1])
```

```
k: 0.4813840693004318
m: 0.8935556114206501
```

Comment: In fact it is!, I was using  a log-log plot to easily get the parameters in the software. But your way to do it simple, direct and is exactly the result that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could linearize your data/model and use least squares:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dat = pd.DataFrame({'Y':[0.0455,0.079,0.059,0.144],'X':[0.055,0.110,0.165,0.220]})

def func(x, y):
    Y = np.log(y)
    X = np.log(x)

    M = np.array((np.ones(len(X)), X)).T

    lnk, m = np.linalg.solve(np.dot(M.T, M), np.dot(M.T, Y))

    return np.exp(lnk), m 


x = dat['X'] 
y = dat['Y']

k, m = func(x, y)

print('k: ', k)
print('m: ', m)

k:  0.2922891128901261
m:  0.6501306234660938
```